# Trouble posting multiple form options to basket

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to post 2 products to a basket from one form in order to order a "set", but when I use the jquery below I end up posting two of one product.

I have two separate drop downs in one form and one add to basket so I am trying to grab one, post to basket, and then loop back to grab other and post.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('form[action="/your-basket/"]').submit(function(e) {
    var $form = $(e.target);
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('/your-basket/', $form.serialize(), function() {
      window.location = '/deal-of-the-week/';
    });
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Post the relevant parts of your form's HTML as well.

Comment: Why are you using AJAX at all if the goal is to redirect?  This is not what ajax was designed to do.   If you want to redirect after, just submit the form manually.  You are actually doing twice as much work this way.

Comment: I am trying to post 2 products from one page so you can select size x of product a, and y of product b within same click, selecting drop down size options in form.

In essence trying to identify and post two selections from one form to make the UX better.